# Smashing Stack on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, x86, segmentation-fault, stack

Did any of you face the following problem when you try to overwrite the `$esp` pointer?

Of course trying a legit buffer size always works! But, when you try to increase the buffer size to overwrite the `$esp` and you manage to success to touch the first byte, second byte, or third byte of `$esp` it works perfectly. But, as soon as you try to overwrite the whole 4 bytes of the `$esp` it totally changes the content of it as well as the address. It doesn't show `41`s any more as I used "A"s to fill the buffer. I've attached a screen shot maybe it will explain in more details. Thanks all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buffer[500];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: smash attempt]

Answer (score 5):

This is related to the implementation of [NX emulation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#nx) in the 32-bit non-PAE Ubuntu kernels, and when the CPU exception is raised. For memory regions below the NX emulation line (i.e. "within" the emulated NX area: from address 0 to the end of the program's text segment -- less than the 0x08049000 end-address of this binary in `/proc/$pid/maps`), the segfault is delivered after EIP has landed on the actual invalid address. For addresses above the line, the fault gets triggered through a different path that reports the failure without moving EIP forward to faulting address, staying instead on the "ret" instruction that leads to the fault.

You can see this in gdb:

```
(gdb) x/1i $pc
=> 0x8048454 <main+64>: ret    
(gdb) info reg esp
esp            0xbffff54c       0xbffff54c
(gdb) x/wx $esp
0xbffff54c:     0x41414141
```

You can also see the difference in how the faults are reported in `dmesg` output. This is the output associated with the "508" attempt:

```
[  585.913896] a.out[1528] general protection ip:8048454 sp:bff1e8ec error:0 in a.out[8048000+1000]
```

And this is for "507":

```
[  598.999760] a.out[1531]: segfault at 414141 ip 00414141 sp bfcac2c0 error 4 in libc-2.13.so[5e7000+178000]
```

If you boot with the PAE kernel installed, `sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-pae`, and you have a PAE capable CPU, you'll see the behavior you'd expect (since NX emulation will be disabled in favor of hardware NX), and all 4 attempts will segfault with the expected EIPs.